# APT Update Error Help

Tags: updates, ppa

I'm getting the following error when trying to do apt-update.  Does anyone know a quick fix for this?  Thanks in advance.

```
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hda-me/nginx-stable/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hda-me/nginx-stable/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `hda-me/nginx-stable` doesn't support Ubuntu 20.04. You can remove this repository using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:hda-me/nginx-stable
```